# What does "pay you out" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I came across the following passage of text in one of the original *Thomas the Tank Engine* stories, and realised there was a phrase in there that I didn't understand.

> "Be careful with the coaches, James" said Edward, "they don't like
> being bumped. Trucks are silly and noisy; they need to be bumped and
> taught to behave, but coaches get cross and will ***pay you out***."
>
> *James the Red Engine, Rev W. Awdry (1948)*

So what does "pay you out" mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means ‘take revenge’, as in this quotation from William Thackeray in 1849: ‘You see if I don't pay you out after school—you sneak, you.’ It was still being used well into the twentieth century. It is appropriate in the work of the Rev. Awdry, but seems to be in decline, as [this nGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pay%20you%20out&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows (subject to the ususal cautions about nGrams).

Comment: This would be one example of the sort of disagreements over these stories between those who would modernise the wordings and those who would keep them as they are.

Comment: I suppose a glossary might be an acceeptable compromise.

Comment: Not sure that would work well with the primary target demographic.

Comment: "Well, actually son, that's _not quite_ the end. I've still got to read you the glossary."

Answer (score 3):

It's a somewhat "dated" form that would normally be expressed today as *pay you **back***, meaning *retaliate, settle the score*.